# Заполнить значения NaN методом bfill, в группировке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть таблица:

| user_id | transact_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 1568 |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 1589 |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | 1755 |

Хочу получить заполнение таким образом:

| user_id | transact_id | transact_bfill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 1568 |
| 1 | NaN | 1568 |
| 1 | 1568 | 1568 |
| 1 | NaN | 1589 |
| 1 | NaN | 1589 |
| 1 | 1589 | 1589 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | 1755 |
| 2 | NaN | 1755 |
| 2 | 1755 | 1755 |

Если просто применить метод bfill, то он для 3-х последних строк user_id=1 заполнит 1755, а нужно чтобы осталось NaN, т.к для этого пользователя нет значений для заполнения, т.е должна быть группировка по user_id. Может есть какие-то другие варианты.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan], [1, np.nan], [1, 1568], [1, np.nan], [1, np.nan], [1, 1589], [1, np.nan], [1, np.nan], [1, np.nan], [2, np.nan], [2, np.nan], [2, 1755]], columns=['user_id', 'transact_id'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df['transact_bfill'] = df.groupby('user_id').bfill()
print(df)
```

```
    user_id  transact_id  transact_bfill
0         1          NaN          1568.0
1         1          NaN          1568.0
2         1       1568.0          1568.0
3         1          NaN          1589.0
4         1          NaN          1589.0
5         1       1589.0          1589.0
6         1          NaN             NaN
7         1          NaN             NaN
8         1          NaN             NaN
9         2          NaN          1755.0
10        2          NaN          1755.0
11        2       1755.0          1755.0
```